# How to force Blender to use modified material image

Tags: edit-mode

After making lots of modifications to my model (after applying an image as a material) I decided to change part of one of the material images applied to PART of one of the mesh parts of my model. When I reopen (open recent) the changes I made to the material image are not there. I suspect that Blender somehow remembers what the image was when first applied. Is there a method to force Blender to use the updated image? Or do I need to start again using the modified image?

Comment: The thumbnails of images are indeed cached. But you should see the changes you made in the Image Editor when the image is displayed in a large size. There you also have the menu entry *Image > Reload* to force a reload from disk.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that the menu entry Image > Reload is only available in teh Image Editor? When I select the Image Editor (shift + F10) there is nothing displayed so I select (menu) Image and only New, Open and Open Cached Render (options) are displayed. I select Open, navigate to the image file which displays the image (and 'reload' appears as an option) then back Object mode and I now have the correct image. Thanks

Comment: If you not packed your .blend file, then you have to save manually the images to external files. Only saving the .blend file, won't save the image modifications. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/image/editing.html#save

Comment: I made the changes to the image file using an image editor. I didn't make the changes inside Blender. Maybe I should have worded the question better.